# "OperationalError: 1047 (08S01): WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use" What is the meaning of this error?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mariadb, operationalerror

I am trying to fetch data through SQL server (remote server) with python program. There are more than 5M rows. My program was running smoothly but suddenly I am facing this error "**OperationalError: 1047 (08S01): WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use"**. When I am trying to fire the same query through DBeaver it's working fine. I am stuck here, anyone faced the same problem before?

is it a problem on the remote server itself ? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: yes, of course, I did research. I asked this because I am confused ..  I am here after my initial research. Thanks anyways

Comment: [This](https://www.quora.com/Is-Stack-Overflow-toxic) out of topic but interesting though ... Thanks..!